# Mongo - find with multiple

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Giving I have this data in my mongo collection

```
product_id | original_id | text
1 | "A00149" | "1280 x 1024"
1 | "A00373" | "Black"
2 | "A00149" | "1280 x 1024"
2 | "A00373" | "White"
3 | "A00149" | "1980 x 1200"
3 | "A00373" | "Black"
```

*(I have added quotes around the values in hand - these are not in the real collection)*

With the following query, Im getting 0 results, though I was expecting 1.

product_id = 1 should meet the query.

Can somebody explain me what Im doing wrong?

In SQL the where would look like this

```
WHERE
    (original_id = "A00149" AND text = "1280 x 1024")
    AND 
    (original_id = "A00373" AND text = "Black")
```

And the mongo query

```
db.Filter.find({
   "find":true,
   "query":{
      "$and":[
         {
            "original_id":"A00149",
            "text":"1280 x 1024"
         },
         {
            "original_id":"A00373",
            "text":"Black"
         }
      ]
   },
   "fields":{
      "product_id":1
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is called 'Filter' and you want a query to return the document with product_id = 1 then its simple:

```
db.Filter.find({"product_id" : 1})
```

I maybe misunderstood your question though?

Edit:

try:

```
db.Filter.find({$and: [{"original_id": "A00149", "text": "1280 x 1024"}, {"original_id": "A00373", "text": "Black"}]},{"product_id": 1})
```

see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and

Comment: Yes its misunderstood, I only want product_ids where (original_id = A00149 and text = 1280 x 1024) and (original_id = A00373 and text = Black)